# React Native: ComponentDidMount won't update AsyncStorage.getItem

Tags: react-native, push-notification, state, asyncstorage

In my app I have one class(NotificationScreen) that changes the time before a notification happens (5mins before, 10,20 etc.) The way it uses AsyncStorage with setItem and getItem is as follows:

The componentDidMount updates the state/text to reflect the time that was chosen. It gets the item, and if its initially null (when the user first uses the app) its set to 30 mins before and if not then it gets the value that was chosen.

```
componentDidMount = () =>{
    AsyncStorage.getItem(this.accessKeyTime).then(value => {
      if(value == null){
        this.setState({ timeSelected: '30'})
        console.warn("time set to 30")
      }
      else {
        this.setState({ timeSelected: value})
        console.warn("time set to " + value)
      }
    });
  }
```

This is in the modal picker, when the user chooses the time and presses "Done" AsyncStorage sets the state to whatever "option" is.

```
onSubmit={(option) => {
            AsyncStorage.setItem(this.accessKeyTime, option).then(() => {
              this.setState({ timeSelected: option});
            }).then(console.warn("time set to " + option));
          }}
```

In the other class [Bell.js] (which is a component called by ANOTHER class), where the notifications are made, I have a componentDidMount that changes the state of the timeSelected. So when a user wants to change the amount of time before being notified, they would go to change the time from the NotificationScreen page, and it should reflect back to the Bell.js when the user taps on the bell component.

```
componentDidMount = () =>{

    this.setState({
        fireDate:this.props.fireDate,
        LaunchStatus: this.props.LaunchStatus,
        ID: this.props.ID,
        TitleName: this.props.TitleName,
    });

    AsyncStorage.getItem(this.accessKeyTime).then(value => {
      if(value == null){
        this.setState({ timeSelected: 30*60000}) //Changes to milliseconds
        this.setState({timeShow: 30})
        console.warn("time set to 30")

      }
      else {
        this.setState({ timeSelected: parseInt(value,10)*60000}) // is string at first but changes to int for notification firedate
        this.setState({timeShow: value})
        console.warn("time set to " + value)
      }
    });

  }
```

ERROR: 
 When I change the time in NotificationScreen, it doesn't change in Bell.js until I close app (refresh it) and open it up. What I've tried was putting the getItem from the Bell.js and put it on the onPress for the Bell ICON, that way works however I would have to tap the bell icon twice for it to update to the correct one.

Comment: `componentDidMount` is only ever called once. So it is great for setting values when the component loads, however if the component is never reloaded then the code in there won't update. That is why you see it working when you reload the app.

Comment: @Andrew So would it make sense to put the getItem in the class that the Bell.js is called. This way I can send a prop to the Bell component?

Comment: I don’t know how your app is set up. That might work, it might not.